# No connector for [] error, supervisor and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I'm trying to setup Supervisor on a VPS with Inmotion Hosting. I keep getting this error in the worker.log file:

```
No connector for [].
```

When trying to start the worker.

First I run these two commands:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
sudo supervisorctl update
```

Then this:

```
sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

And that's when I get the error.

.env:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

laravel-worker.conf

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/bin/php xxx/artisan queue:work default --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=xxx
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=xxx/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

I also tried running these commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

But it didn't solve it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. In the laravel-worker.conf file, in the `command` line, `default` should be `database`.
Now it's working.

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/bin/php xxx/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=xxx
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=xxx/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```